# ASP Classic - If test failing

Tags: sql, asp-classic, recordset

I really do not understand why the if test always fails.  I have validated the session variable sCrs_cde (course code) is correct and exists in only one of the multiple records returned by the sql query. (It is part of a foreign key tied to year and semester).  I am trying to sert the value for the course title, but it is always writing out as an empty value ('')

```
Dim Recordset1
Dim Recordset1_cmd
Dim Recordset1_numRows

Set Recordset1_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Recordset1_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_Jenz_STRING
Recordset1_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID_NUM, Crs_Title, YR_CDE, TRM_CDE, CRS_CDE, TRANSACTION_STS, SUBTERM_CDE FROM dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST WHERE ID_NUM = ? And Transaction_sts = 'C' "

Recordset1_cmd.Prepared = true
Recordset1_cmd.Parameters.Append Recordset1_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 5, 1, -1, Recordset1__MMColParam) ' adDouble

Set Recordset1 = Recordset1_cmd.Execute
Recordset1_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Do While not Recordset1.Eof 
   response.write(Recordset1.Fields.Item("CRS_cde").Value)
  IF (Recordset1.Fields.Item("CRS_cde").Value) = (Session("sCrs_cde")) THEN
      Session("sCrs_Title") = (Recordset1.Fields.Item("CRS_Title").Value)
      Session("sYr_cde") = (Recordset1.Fields.Item("YR_CDE").Value)
      Session("sTrm_cde") = (Recordset1.Fields.Item("Trm_Cde").Value)
      Session("sSubterm_cde") = (Recordset1.Fields.Item("Subterm_cde").Value)
      EXIT Do
   ELSE
     Recordset1.movenext
   END IF
Loop
```

Comment: What data type is CRS_cde?   I would save the Session("sCRS_cde") to a variable, make sure it is the same data type (integer), then compare.   If you are comparing an integer to a string, this could explain your problem

Comment: why do you have server tags(`%><%`) before the while loop

Comment: @meda - Probably a consequence of cutting, copying and pasting.  He's closing one script block and opening another on the following line, which is unnecessary, but not actually wrong

Comment: Couldn't you get rid of the if statement all together and use (Session("sCrs_cde") in your SQL query - SELECT ID_NUM, Crs_Title, YR_CDE, TRM_CDE, CRS_CDE, TRANSACTION_STS, SUBTERM_CDE FROM dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST WHERE CRS_CDE = "&Session("sCRS_cde")& " and ID_NUM = ? And Transaction_sts = 'C'

Comment: Also, this code is obviously generated by Dreamweaver.  Dreamweaver's ASP database connection code is hideous.  I recommend you learn how to code it yourself.  http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/database_connection.php

Comment: @John yeah it might not be the cause of the problem just so strange also. I usually use ServerObject to create command, recordset and connections

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.  I made a boneheaded mistake every programming 101 class teaches.  I did not rtrim the values.  I don't know where the extra spaces came from since both values were retrieved from the database (different tables), but after rtrimming both values in the if statement, I finally got it to pass.